# Filter items in QStandardItemModel or QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, filtering, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

I represent same data in **QTreeView** with **QStandardItemModel**. Data is table - I have rows and columns, I get it from DB with QSqlQuery. How can I filter rows based on some column value? For example I have third column some integer value, and by clicking some button I want to show only rows with this *number > 10*. I can perform another **QSqlQuery.exec**, but it is possible to do so with **QTreeView** or **QStandardItemModel**?

Comment: 1. You can use QSqlTableModel instead of filling standard model with data retrieved from query

Comment: @KamilKlimek I need tree view, QSqlTableModel is just a table so doesn't suit me

Comment: 2. You can use QSortFilterProxyModel or any kind of proxy model to filter data. Also you can use it to format data.

Comment: @KamilKlimek oh, seems it's just what I wanted! Going to try it

Comment: @KamilKlimek will you form an answer for this question for me accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To filter out data you may use [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). By overriding other methods you can format data in underlying model, so there is no need to fill QStandardItemModel on your own and use QSqlTable model as a source instead.